# Starting a new thread on a web page button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have inherited a legacy app and there is some code that can be simplified down to:

```
protected void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var otherThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
        FireAnAsyncProcess();
    });
    otherThread.Start();

    thankYouPanel.Visible = true;
    otherPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

The `FireAnAsyncProcess()` seems to be intermittently failing to run. This could of course be a number of things but I wondered:
Given the pause of `20000` above, will `FireAnAsyncProcess()` always be called even after the button click has been handled? Does the new thread get called regardless of what happens to the thread that called it?

Edit: the result/outcome of `FireAnAsyncProcess()` is not required on the web page and the page is not intending to wait for them. Rather it is trying to start the thread and assume it gets fired.

Comment: would something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559215/tasks-and-thread-scheduling-in-asp-net or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600926/Asynchronous-web-services-call-in-ASP-NET help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is web environment - each request is handled in their own thread context, and the `Thread.Start()` isn't useful: the child thread will be aborted after the request been handled, and the parent thread aborted.

So if you need to run some piece of work on `Button_Click`, you should host a WCF service or Windows Service or something being able to accept some message from web-application and run the job in background.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the case. Thank you for that explanation.

Comment: This isn't true - threads are roots, they will never be collected while running (and this thread *has* been started). This still doesn't mean this is a good idea, necessarily - the hosting environment can terminate the thread whenever it wants. However, the real problem is likely somewhere else - most likely, the `FireAnAsyncProcess` is trying to access the request context or something like that.

Comment: This threads will not be collected with GC, that's true, but the tasks they are running will be cancelled, that's what I was trying to say. I user will be lucky enough, the thread may even be finished, but this is quite unstable and error-prone solution.